# How to use findNavController() in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am currently doing code refactoring for a current Kotlin application.
I would like to move to a different fragment by pressing a button from the Compose view.
I know that Compose has own navigator, but can I somehow use findNavController() in Compose files?
I tried sending a function to Compose files but I still get the error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot add views to ComposeView; only Compose content is supported
```

Current code:

Code in fragment:

```
binding.composeProgram.setContent {
        MdcTheme {
            ProgramContent(
                viewModel = viewModel,
                navigationController = {
                    findNavController().navigate(
                        R.id.exercise_details,
                        ExerciseDetailFragmentArgs(396).toBundle(),
                        null,
                        null
                    )
                }
            )
        }
    }
```

Compose file:

```
@Composable
fun ProgramContent(
    viewModel: ProgramFragmentViewModel,
    navigationController:  () -> (Unit)
) {
    Button(onClick = {
        navigationController()
    }){}
}
```

SOLVED:
I had to add to xmlns file one line:

```
android:transitionGroup="true"
```

So in xmlns file it will looks like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/AppTheme.Fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:transitionGroup="true"
    >

<androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
        android:id="@+id/compose_program"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
...
```

Comment: Thanks, the transitionGroup solved my issue. Can you add it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add to xmlns file one line:

```
android:transitionGroup="true"
```

So in xmlns file it will looks like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/AppTheme.Fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:transitionGroup="true"
    >

<androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
        android:id="@+id/compose_program"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
...
```